# Unable to find interceptor class referenced by ref-name jsonValidationWorkflowStack

Tags: java, struts2, struts2-json-plugin, struts2-interceptors

In my Struts2 application I have the following action in `struts.xml`

```xml
<action name="submitRecruitmentProcess" method="submitRecruitmentProcess"
            class="com.erp.people.action.RecruitementProcessManagementAction">
            <result name="success">jsp/process/processlist.jsp</result>         
            <interceptor-ref name="jsonValidationWorkflowStack"></interceptor-ref>
            <result name="input" type="json">
                <param name="ignoreHierarchy">false</param>
                <param name="includeProperties">actionErrors\[\d+\], fieldErrors\..+$,
                    actionMessages\[\d+\]</param>
            </result>    
        </action>
```

I am extending the `json-default` in ma struts.xml  file and also using struts-json pluggin in my classpath. But on running the application I am getting an error like the following

**Unable to find interceptor class referenced by ref-name jsonValidationWorkflowStack**

Any idea on what is going wrong,any help is appreciated.

I have followed [this](http://www.javawebdevelop.com/582612/) link

### web.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_9" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>Struts2</display-name>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher
        </filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>jsp/login/login.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <context-param>
    <param-name>
      org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.DEFINITIONS_CONFIG
    </param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

</web-app>
```

Comment: You'll need to provide further information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says that you have not placed the struts2 json plugin jar file in classpath (i.e in `WEB-INF/lib`). Get the `struts2-json-plugin-2.3.20.jar` and put it in classpath to fix the issue. If you have downloaded struts2 Jars then this Jar file can be seen as part of the downloaded package.

While checking the [link](http://www.javawebdevelop.com/582612/) you have provided I have observed few issues if you want to use **`Struts2-2.3.20`**.

1) The `DOCTYPE` declaration in `struts.xml` is not correct. It should be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">
<struts>
    <package name="default" extends="json-default">
        <action name="login" class="com.examples.action.LoginAction">
            <interceptor-ref name="jsonValidationWorkflowStack"></interceptor-ref>
            <result name="input" type="json">
                <param name="ignoreHierarchy">false</param>
                <param name="includeProperties">actionErrors\[\d+\], fieldErrors\..+$,
                    actionMessages\[\d+\]</param>
            </result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

I just named the login class with different package for testing.

Also the `DOCTYPE` declaration for validation.xml file is not proper, it should be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>   

<!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC "-//Apache Struts//XWork Validator 1.0.3//EN"
        "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/xwork-validator-1.0.3.dtd">
```

Now coming to plugins, if you do not have the JSON plugin in classpath then you will get runtime exception as:

```
Caused by: Parent package is not defined: json-default
```

To fix this add `struts2-json-plugin-2.3.20` in `WEB-INF/lib` of your application so it will be in classpath.

Now as the JSP pages are using JQuery tags you have to place the `struts2-jquery-plugin-2.5.3.jar` in classpath.

I have tested it with `Struts2-2.3.20` version, correct your code and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: Your doctypes are wrong.

Comment: @AleksandrM, which one? as per this link the validation doctype in my answer is correct --> https://struts.apache.org/docs/validation.html

Comment: All of them. And NO check the link.

Comment: @AleksandrM, aslo check this for struts.xml file doctype -- https://struts.apache.org/docs/create-struts-2-web-application-using-maven-to-manage-artifacts-and-to-build-the-application.html

Comment: @AleksandrM, I am referring to struts2 official documenatation, so are you saying the official doc is giving wrong information?

Comment: Official docs are ok. Double check what is in your answer and in the docs.

Comment: @AleksandrM, Thanks Alaex, I observed that I have mentioned the Doctype version as 1.0.2 instead of 1.0.3 for validation.xml, I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: There is `struts-2.3.dtd` also.

Comment: @AleksandrM, as per official doc, they say to use 2.0 dtd, I am following that https://struts.apache.org/docs/hello-world-using-struts-2.html

Comment: It is outdated tutorial.

Comment: @AleksandrM, Thank you, updated answer to refer to latest DTD

Comment: @Chaitanya Thank you for the answer, I haven't noticed the struts2json  jar  version , The struts2json pluggin which I was using as mentioned in the link was caused the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

The `interceptor-ref` tag should not have an empty body, so you need to simplify its usage

```
<interceptor-ref name="jsonValidationWorkflowStack"/>
```

This interceptor stack is available in the `json-default` package that your pacakge should extend, i.e.

```
<package name="default" extends="json-default">
```

The json plugin should be on class path *at runtime*.

Comment: No , still the same error..

Comment: What I can't see on your link is a `web.xml`. Could you post it to the question?

Comment: What is the class name for the  jsonValidationWorkflowStack  so that I can check for that classname in the pluggin . I am using the struts2-json-plugin-2.1.8.1 jar file

Comment: The web.xml which I have added is what I am using, its not from the link I have given

Comment: It's for a different Struts version, sot you can't use it. Also see [this](http://struts.apache.org/docs/webxml.html#web.xml-SimpleExample), because `org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher` is deprecated.

Comment: No , still the issue is there .Thank you for  all your quick responses.

Comment: Still the issue, means either you didn't understand the answer or you have hidden something, or doing something wrong that you didn't mention.